# Анимация метки вдоль линии. При больших расстояниях метка перемещается не по линии, а по дуге

Tags: yandex-maps-api

На карте расположены объекты. Между объектами установлены связи. Связь между объектами отображается на карте как линия. По линии должен перемещаться объект Метка.

Проблема в том, что на длинных расстояниях Метка бежит не по линии, а по дуге рядом с линией. Дуга это часть окружности большого диаметра, а линия между объектами это хорда которая пересекает эту дугу. На коротких расстояниях это незаметно, а на длинных бросается в глаза.

Как сделать так чтобы метка бежала точно по линии? Допустимо соединять объекты не прямыми линиями, а дугами. Визуально это будет выглядеть как прямая линия.

Расчеты сделаны в координатной системе coordSystem.cartesian описывающей геометрию декартовой плоскости.

Пример нужно развернуть пример на всю страницу.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    ymaps.ready(init);
    
    function init () {
        var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
                center: [52, 75],     
                controls: ['zoomControl','typeSelector'],
                zoom: 5   
            },                
            );
            
        // Объект Линия 
        var data_line = {
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "features": []
            }
        // Объект метка
        var data_star = {
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "features": []
            }
        
        var start_coordinates = [55.0415,89.9343];
        var finish_coordinates = [43.4199,39.9474];
            
        // Создаем объект Линия
        var item_line = {
            "type": "Feature", 
            "id": 1, 
            "options": {
                "strokeWidth": 1,
                "strokeColor": "#255F06"
                },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString", 
                "coordinates": [start_coordinates,finish_coordinates]  
                },
            } 
        data_line.features[0] = item_line; 

        // Создаем объект метка которая будет бежать по линии
        var item_star = {
            "type": "Feature", 
            "id": 1, 
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point", 
                "coordinates": start_coordinates
                },
            "properties": {
                // Координаты бегущего шарика: Начало и Конец 
                start: start_coordinates,
                finish: finish_coordinates
                }                            
            }  
        data_star.features[0] = item_star; 
        
        var  objectManager_line = new ymaps.ObjectManager();
        myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager_line);
        objectManager_line.add(data_line);

        var  objectManager_star = new ymaps.ObjectManager();
        myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager_star);
        objectManager_star.add(data_star);
        
        setTimeout(animatePoint, 100);

        // Светящаяся Метка бежит по линии
        function animatePoint() {
          var step = 0;
          
          setInterval(function() {
            var object;
            var iterator = objectManager_star.objects.getIterator();  
            while ((object = iterator.getNext()) != iterator.STOP_ITERATION) {
                
                // if (step>0) {
                    var start = object.properties.start;
                    var finish = object.properties.finish;
                    
                    var path = ymaps.coordSystem.cartesian.solveInverseProblem(start, finish).pathFunction;
                    var position = path(step/10).point;
                    object.geometry.coordinates = position;
                // }
            }
            myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager_star);
            
            if (step>=10) step=0;
            else  step++;
          }, 1000);
        };
    }        
       
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo. Метка бегущая вдоль линии</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru-RU&amp;apikey=978c8365-3c1b-4757-bc96-35dd14045e22" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://yandex.st/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/demo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <style>
        html, body, #map {
            width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Пробовал преобразовывать географические координаты в пиксельные и обратно (function animatePoint()). Результат тот же. Метка бежит по кривой вдоль линии.

Пример нужно развернуть пример на всю страницу.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    ymaps.ready(init);
    
    function init () {
        var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
                center: [52, 75],     // center: [55.76, 37.64],
                controls: ['zoomControl','typeSelector'],
                zoom: 5    // 4
            },                
            );
            
        // Объект Линия 
        var data_line = {
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "features": []
            }
        // Объект метка
        var data_star = {
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "features": []
            }
        
        var start_coordinates = [55.0415,89.9343];
        var finish_coordinates = [43.4199,39.9474];
            
        // Создаем объект Линия
        var item_line = {
            "type": "Feature", 
            "id": 1, 
            "options": {
                "strokeWidth": 1,
                "strokeColor": "#255F06"
                },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString", 
                "coordinates": [start_coordinates,finish_coordinates]  
                },
            } 
        data_line.features[0] = item_line; 

        // Создаем объект метка которая будет бежать по линии
        var item_star = {
            "type": "Feature", 
            "id": 1, 
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point", 
                "coordinates": start_coordinates
                },
            "properties": {
                // Координаты бегущего шарика: Начало и Конец 
                start: start_coordinates,
                finish: finish_coordinates
                }                            
            }  
        data_star.features[0] = item_star; 
        
        var  objectManager_line = new ymaps.ObjectManager();
        myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager_line);
        objectManager_line.add(data_line);

        var  objectManager_star = new ymaps.ObjectManager();
        myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager_star);
        objectManager_star.add(data_star);
        
        setTimeout(animatePoint, 100);

        // Метка бежит по линии
        function animatePoint() {
          var step = 0;
          
          setInterval(function() {
            var projection = myMap.options.get('projection');
            var zoom = myMap.getZoom();
                
            var object;
            var iterator = objectManager_star.objects.getIterator();  
            
            while ((object = iterator.getNext()) != iterator.STOP_ITERATION) {
                var start = object.properties.start;
                var finish = object.properties.finish;
                
                var start_px = projection.fromGlobalPixels(start, zoom);
                var finish_px = projection.fromGlobalPixels(finish, zoom);
                var ln_x = finish_px[0] - start_px[0];
                var ln_y = finish_px[1] - start_px[1];
        
                var dx = ln_x /10;
                var dy = ln_y /10;
                
                if (step>0) {
                    cur_px = [start_px[0] + (dx*step), start_px[1] + (dy*step)];
                    var cur_coord = projection.toGlobalPixels(cur_px, zoom);
                    object.geometry.coordinates = cur_coord;
                }
            }
            myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager_star);
            
            if (step>=10) step=0;
            else  step++;
          }, 1000);
        };
    }        
       
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo. Метка бегущая вдоль линии</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru-RU&amp;apikey=978c8365-3c1b-4757-bc96-35dd14045e22" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://yandex.st/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/demo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <style>
        html, body, #map {
            width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: постарайтесь уменьшить количество кода

Comment: Дело в том, что в проекции меркатора "Параллели представляют собой параллельные линии, расстояние между которыми вблизи экватора равно расстоянию между меридианами и быстро увеличивается при приближении к полюсам." поэтому поделив на 10 вы не получаете точку лежащую на линии по вертикали, а получаете точку немного смещённую к экватору. Я вижу такие решения: 1. Воспользоваться https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/ILineStringGeometryAccess-docpage/#method_detail__getClosest и ставить метку на точку ближайшую к линии 2. Создать линию из точек и прыгать по этим точкам.